# MainView in iOS phonegap functionality breaks after closing ChildBrowser

Tags: objective-c, ios5, cordova, childbrowser

I am using phonegap version 2.2.0 and have installed ChildBrowser plugin code to XCode project, plugin loads fine with no problem. When navigating to a static html page in the main view which has bunch of

tags and each tag has link to external page. Once you click that external link the ChildBrowser loads as expected, but when I close the ChildBrowser by clicking "Done" button the original view is there as expected. but when you try to scroll in that main view the scrolling part quits working, I am no longer able to scroll that page? I added following **[[self parentViewController] reloadInputViews]** line and thought that may solve the issue, but the problem still remains. Also, it whacks out the original stlye meaning the buttons and font looks larger. Some how the original webview needs to maintain it correct state. Please suggest any corrections.

I was looking at the close button event code 
\Plugins\ChildBrowserViewController.m

```
- (void)closeBrowser
  {
      if (self.delegate != nil) {
         [self.delegate onClose];
      }
      if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]) {
         // Reference UIViewController.h Line:179 for update to iOS 5 difference - @RandyMcMillan
           [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
      } else {
          [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
          [[self parentViewController] reloadInputViews];
      }
  }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?? I'm having the same issue.